# Skipping lines and splitting them into columns in python text parser

Tags: python

I am attempting to parse a space delimited text file in python 2.7.5 which looks kind of like:

```
variable         description      useless data
a1                asdfsdf           2342354 
            Sometimes it goes into further detail about the 
            variable/description here
a2                asdsfda           32123
```

EDIT:Sorry about the spaces added in the beginning, i did not see them

I want to be able to split the text file into an array with variable and description in 2 separate columns, and cut all the useless data and skip any lines that do not start with a string. The way I have set up my code to start is:

```
import os
import pandas
import numpy
os.chdir('C:\folderwithfiles')
f = open('Myfile.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    else:
        print(line)
print(lines)
```

As of right now, this code skips most of the descriptive lines between variable lines, however some still pop up in the parsing. If I could get any help with either troubleshooting my line skips or help me to get started on the column forming part that would be great! I also do not have a lot of expirience in python. Thanks!

EDIT: A part of the file before code

```
CASEID            (id) Case Identification                   1   15   AN



MIDX              (id) Index to Birth History                16   1  No
                           1:6
```

After:

```
CASEID            (id) Case Identification                   1   15   AN

MIDX              (id) Index to Birth History                16   1  No
                           1:6
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with `if not line.strip()` ?

Comment: @JustinL: he's skipping empty lines with that code

Comment: [ and ] are not apart of the text file, i will edit them out

Comment: Is the text file space delimited or tab delimited? And does every line begin with a space as shown? Please post a representative sample of the text file

Comment: @inspectorG4dget it looks like he also is expecting it to skip the description lines?

Comment: @JustinL.: well, he wants that functionality, but that LOC won't do the trick.

Comment: Please post a representative sample of the input file

Comment: As a side note, [there is no reason for that `lines = f.readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html). Just use `for line in f:` and you don't need `lines`.

Comment: Your question says "As of right now, this code skips most of the descriptive lines between variable lines". But when I copy and paste your code and run it on your sample input, it does not skip _any_ of the description lines. So… is that not your code, or is that not your input?

Comment: @ inspector- those spaces were added in on accident

Comment: @bhg23442: With the edited version of your input, I _still_ don't get any lines skipped with your code. Nor would I expect to. So again, please confirm that the code and data you're asking about are the same code and data you're giving us.

Comment: Yes it is my data and code

Comment: OK, your latest version only has 1 description line in the input, and you're not skipping it in the output. So in what sense is that skipping most of the descriptive lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter out lines that start with spaces, and split all other lines to get the first two columns.

Translating those two rules into code:

```
with open('Myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith(' '):
            variable, description, _ = line.split(None, 2)
            print(variable, description)
```

That's all there is to it.

---

Or, translating even more directly:

```
with open('Myfile.txt') as f:
    non_descriptions = filter(lambda line: not line.startswith(' '), f)
    values = (line.split(None, 2) for line in non_descriptions)
```

Now `values` is an iterator over `(variable, description)` tuples. And it's nice and declarative. The first line means "filter out lines that start with space". The second means "split each line to get the first two columns". (You could write the first as a genexpr instead of filter, or the second as map instead of a genexpr, but I think this is the closest to the English description.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no spaces in your variables or descriptions, this will work

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = []
    for line in file:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        if line.startswith(' '): # skipping descriptions
            continue
        splits = line.split()
        var, desc = splits[:2]
        answer.append([var, desc])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas try this:

```
from pandas import read_csv
data = read_csv('file.txt', error_bad_lines=False).drop(['useless data'])
```

If your file is fixed-width (as opposed to comma-separated-values) then use [`pandas.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns)